# Javascript Content doesn't display until second click

Tags: javascript

When I first load the page it takes two clicks to show the content but then after that, every click will either show or hide. So it works... just not right away.

```js
function navClick() {
  var content = document.querySelector('.dropdown-content');

  if (content.style.display == 'none') {
    content.style.display = 'block';
  } else {
    content.style.display = 'none';
  }
};
```

```css
.dropbtn {
  position: relative;
  float: right;
  font-size: 35px;
  color: #fff;
  margin-top: -50px;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
  ;
  margin-right: 30px;
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: 2;
  display: nne;
}
```

```html
<a class="dropbtn" onclick="navClick()"><i class="ion-ios-menu"></i></a>
<div class="dropdown col">
  <ul class="dropdown-content">
    <li><a href="eguitarindex.html">Guitars</a></li>
    <li><a href="drumsindex.html">Drums</a></li>
    <li><a href="ampsindex.html">Amps</a></li>
    <li><a href="gearindex.html">Gear</a></li>
    <li><a href="#featured">Featured</a></li>
    <li class="find-us"><a href="#find-us">Find Us</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

What is happening here and how can I make the function work the first time a user clicks?

Comment: Try putting `console.log(content.style.display)` in the function and I think you'll see why.

Comment: Is the CSS you posted supposed to be for `.dropdown-content`?

Comment: In fact, unless you have specifically set `style="display:none"` on the element in question, `content.style.display` will always be an empty string initially. @Barmar's debugging suggestion above would show you this

Comment: The `.style` property doesn't contain styles inherited from CSS. You have to use `getComputedStyle()` for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `content.style.display` isn't defined, so it isn't `none` when you click, so it is set as `none`, next time through it is `none` so it changes to `block`. I would recommend using `classList.toggle` instead though:

```js
function navClick() {
  var content = document.querySelector('.dropdown-content');
  content.classList.toggle('hidden');
};
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<a class="dropbtn" onclick="navClick()">Toggle Menu</a>
<div class="dropdown col">
  <ul class="dropdown-content">
    <li><a href="eguitarindex.html">Guitars</a></li>
    <li><a href="drumsindex.html">Drums</a></li>
    <li><a href="ampsindex.html">Amps</a></li>
    <li><a href="gearindex.html">Gear</a></li>
    <li><a href="#featured">Featured</a></li>
    <li class="find-us"><a href="#find-us">Find Us</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think it happens because ul tag doesn't have style attribute, so you can add it as follow:

```html
<ul class="dropdown-content" style="display: block;">
```

You can also change in css:

```css
display: nne;
```

to

```css
display: none;
```

Comment: I get the feeling OP wants to start with `display:none`